# mvn clean compile works BUT mvn install fails on compilation

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I run `mvn clean compile` on my project I get a build success.

But when I run `mvn install` straight afterwards, I get a Build Failure because of a compilation error.

The error I get is:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project auto-tests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

I have this in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The failure is because it cannot find the classes which sit in another module. The dependency for these classes is added in my pom file and intellij never complains about it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the actual compile error?

Comment: the error that is getting returned is: package com.xx.xxx.xxxservice does not exist

Comment: the funny thing is, is that in intelliJ everything builds fine and I never get any of these packages complaining as i have a dependency in my pom.xml it only throws this error when I try to run the tests from the command line.

Comment: The likely reason for that is that IntelliJ probably combines all of the dependencies into one big classpath that it uses to build everything.  Maven command line builds have separate compile, test-compile, and run classpaths.  What is the pom's `<dependency>` entry for com.xx.xxx.xxxservice?

Answer (score 3):

It's "testCompile" mojo that fails, which is called inside the "test-compile" phase, a phase between "compile" and "install".

So basically your test sources cannot compile.

Comment: How would I resolve my issue then? any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you should have the compilation issue explained in detail in the Maven output. This is just a compilation issue anyway.

Comment: @user3194793: try `mvn site` for miscellaneous info on your project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably have a compile error in one of your tests (which don't get compiled in the normal `compile` phase).  It's hard to tell exactly where without a full pom and source code.